# Disable the submit button if no radio button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

```
<tr>
    <td height="250px" width="300px"><center><label><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"><img src="../paymentoptions/lbc.png" alt="LBC" class="picture" width="245px" style="margin:10px"/></label></td>

    <td height="250px" width="300px"><center><label><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"><img src="../paymentoptions/pickup.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture" height="210px" width="250px" style="margin:10px"/></label></td>
</tr>
```

Hello, How do i disable my form submit button if no option is chosen? thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Wow... `<center>` tag..! do you know the fact that it is deprecated..?

Answer (score 7):

Well they are radio buttons, so they can't be unchecked. Start with the button disabled and toggle it to enabled if/when one of the radio buttons is checked:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="submit" name="submit"/>

//Begin JS

$(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){

        $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false);
        //Or
        //$("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfzzgah8/1/)

Comment: @VinceAgno if this is helps to you, can you please mark as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#submit_button").submit(function(){
    var temp = false;
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
             temp = true;
        }
    });
    if(temp == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false
});
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I would think it is because he wants to enable a disabled button. E.g. he wouldn't be able to fire the submit event if the button is already disabled.